# Getting a KeyNotFoundException when building ViewModel

Tags: dd4t

In `ComponentController.cs` in the `DD4t.Web.mvc` project I am getting the following error:

> KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by usercode
>
> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

The Exception occurs when I get to the line:

```cs
var model = ViewModelBuilder.Build(componentPresentation);
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception is probably just a simple exception telling you that the `Build` method is trying to read a field value of a field in a Component's `IFieldSet`dictionary for a dictionary key that is defined in your code, but not set in the published component.

Edit the `Build` method to always check whether a field actually consists in the published component:

```
if (tridionComponent.Fields.ContainsKey("title"))
{
    Title = tridionComponent.Fields["title"].Value;
}// else return an empty string, or throw the exception if the field is really always needed
```

It always helps to ensure that values are set properly in Tridion Components by setting the field in the Component's Schema to Mandatory. In any case, I personally always find it better to log an error stating that the field isn't present rather than to kill the whole page, therefore I always program my view models as defensively as possible.